# Find invisible elements inside scrollable div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a scrollable `div` having `overflow:scroll`. What I want is to add the some CSS class on the elements that are currently visible in scrollable `div` when I scroll `div`  and also at a same time I have to add some CSS class having `display:none` to currently invisible element in scrollable `div`.

Comment: WHAT ?! do you mean you need a fixed element inside your scrollable div so it will stay at the same position while you scroll ?

Answer (score 1):

I cooked up an example for you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollable">
    <div class="hidden">Hidden</div>
    <div>Visible</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden{display:none};

.something{background: red;}

.something-else{background: blue;}
```

**Jquery/Javascript**

```
var hiddenElements= $("#scrollable div:hidden");
hiddenElements.addClass("something");
var visibleElements = $("#scrollable div:visible");
visibleElements.addClass("something-else");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqRCk/1/